# Understanding the Shortest Job First Algorithm (Non-preemptive)

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, job-scheduling

The shortest job first algorithm is shown in the following image:

[image: SJF]

If it is shortest job first/shortest process next, shouldn't the order be:
P1 → P5 → P3 → P4 → P2 ? Since that's the order of lowest to highest service times.

Why does process 2 come second?

I know if we use burst times instead, that would be the order, but I have no idea what the differences between service time and burst times are.

Any help would be much appreciated explaining that graphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image in the question follows the correct order which is:

> P1 → P2 → P5 → P3 → P4

**Explanation:**

`P1` is arrived at `time = 0` , so it will be executed first. Service Time of this process is `3`. So this process is completed at `time=3`.

At `time=3`, there is only one process that is arrived which is `P2`. All other processes arrive later. So this process is now executed. Service time of this process is `6`, so this process is completed at `time=3+6=9`.

Now at `time=9`, there are three processes which are `P3`, `P4` and `P5` (which arrived at `time= 4, 6 and 8` respectively). Since the service time of `P5` is `2` which is minimum as compared to that of `P3` and `P4`, so `P5` is now executed and it gets completed at `time=9+2=11`.

At `time=11`, we have two processes which are `P3` and `P4` (which are arrived at `time= 4 and 6` respectively). Since the service time of `P3` is `4` which is less as compared to that of `P4`, so `P4` is executed now and it gets completed at `time= 11+4=15`

At `time=15`, we have only one process which is `P4`. So it is executed now. Since service time of this process is `5`, so it gets completed at `time = 15+5 = 20`

Comment: I guess the source of confusion is that the image indicated the final schedule, and not the arrivals and durations of the incoming jobs. For instance, job 4 comes in at 6, but only gets scheduled at 15 instead.